# EF Core 'Cannot Load Assembly' error when scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework, scaffolding

I am unsure why I am getting the error, especially since I am able to add migrations and update the database using a code first approach. It is only now that I am attempting to scaffold a new database that  I am getting the error.

Lairage.Blazor - Startup.cs

```
// Add the Innova Connection
services.AddContext<InnovaContext>(Configuration.GetConnectionString("InnovaConnection"));
```

Lairage.Context.Sql - ServiceCollectionExtentions

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtentions
{
        
        public static IServiceCollection AddContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionstring, ServiceLifetime serviceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Scoped) where TContext : DbContext => services
            .AddDbContext<TContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
                    connectionstring,
                    actions => actions.MigrationsAssembly("Lairage.Context.Sql")
                                      .EnableRetryOnFailure()
                ), serviceLifetime);

}
```

Error:

> Could not load assembly 'Lairage.Context.Sql'. Ensure it is referenced by the startup project 'Lairage.Blazor'.

Package Manager Default Class:

I have my Package Manager setup to the default project **Lairage.Context.Sql**.

Command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=<***>;Initial Catalog=<***>;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Innova
```

Comment: I did face a similar issue when trying to add migration using ASP.Net Core 3.1. 
My problem was that the only project referencing EntityFrameworkCore, EntityFrameworkCore.Design, EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer and EntityFrameworkCore.Tools was the one which had DbContext in it. I had to reference all these packages in startup project too to get it working. I am still not sure about the reason it worked, but I would suggest trying that